# Erro na contagem de caracteres maiúsculos

Tags: jquery, html

Estou criando uma função no `jquery` onde o usuário ao digitar a sua senha, esta função identifica quantos caracteres maiúsculos existem nesta senha, para fazer o calculo da força dessa senha. 
Eu até consegui fazer com que essa função conte os caracteres maiúsculos, mas mesmo assim eu não consegui obter o resultado desejado. 
Por exemplo: a função consegue contar os caracteres maiúsculos quando estão no começo da senha, porém se o usuário digitar um caracter minúsculo, os próximos caracteres maiúsculos não serão contados, e é ai que surge o problema. 
Aqui está o link dos testes que eu realizei: [Aqui!](http://jsfiddle.net/2r3e1dwr/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outra alternativa usando *regex*.

```
$("#senha").change(function(){
    var senha = $("#senha").val();

    $('#teste').html(senha.replace(/[^A-Z]+/g, '').length);
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/dyunekLs/1/)</kbd>

A expressão `[^A-Z]+` vai corresponder apenas a caracteres no intervalo de *A-Z*.

Comment: Não está certa @QMechanic! por que para mim só interessa a letras maiúsculas e a função retorna um valor maior. Tente digitar nessa forma a senha: AeAeeFG.

Comment: @BrunoDuarte Veja agora.

Comment: Correto @QMechanic, funcionou perfeitamente. Vlw, abraço.

Answer (score 3):

Eu faria da seguinte forma:
Ao mudar o valor do campo "senha", percorreria a string do mesmo char a char verificando se está presente no intervalo [65-90], que corresponde aos valores [A-Z] em código ASCII.

```
$("#senha").change(function(){
    var senha = $("#senha").val();
    var qtdMaiuscula = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < senha.length; i++)
        if(senha.charCodeAt(i) >= 65 && senha.charCodeAt(i) <= 90)
            qtdMaiuscula++;
    $('#teste').html( qtdMaiuscula );
});
```

Um código um pouco mais claro, que surte o mesmo efeito:

```
$("#senha").change(function(){
    var senha = $("#senha").val();
    var qtdMaiuscula = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < senha.length; i++)
        if(senha[i] >= 'A' && senha[i] <= 'Z')
            qtdMaiuscula++;
    $('#teste').html( qtdMaiuscula );
});
```

Comment: Olá @Luis, pois então, eu estou fazendo desta forma por que no meu layout original eu irei implementar uma barra em degradê com as cores vermelho para senhas incorretas, amarelo para senhas razoáveis e verde para senhas corretas, tudo isso dinamicamente conforme o usuário vai digitando, entendeu?